# I use Windows and Ubuntu together. I want to uninstall Windows

Tags: windows, uninstall

I use Ubuntu and Windows together but now I want to uninstall  Windows.

OS uninstaller and `gparted` were recommended to me.

Do any files or documents in Windows C: hard disk get harmed or deleted?

Comment: All of the answers below contain possibly dangerous pitfalls. **[Back up first!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)** because the correct answer is: *it depends on your Windows setup* but my left telepathic antenna is broken off, so I cannot telepathically link with your Windows C:-drive for the moment... **;-)** Please [edit] your question and provide the output of the following command under Windows: `tree \ | more`

Answer (score 0):

sure if you delete your windows partion all your data from windows are away if you safe your data on an another partion (like d:) they are save

Comment: That depends on what D:\ (would be e.g. /dev/sda2 in Ubuntu!) is. Some tools wipe everything that has to do something with Windows, even data partitions. Using an external HDD or doing a backup on DVDs is much safer. Any partitioning is always risky too. And of course he has to have another win-readable partition on his drive.

Comment: Duncan, very dangerous to start your advice with "Sure" when you should start with: **If and only if your data is safely on another partition** can you delete it...

Answer (score 0):

If you use OS-Uninstaller is performs a complete wipe of the entire partition.  This means all data on that partition will be deleted.  If there is any data you wish to save you can back it up prior to removing windows.  I would suggest mounting the windows partition and use your file browser in Ubuntu to copy desired files into your home folder.